# Matrix associativity in tensorflow tf.matmul issues

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication

We have a matrix M with shape (n, n) and a matrix C with shape (n, n). In this example, both matrices are generate using numpy's `np.random.normal()`. We are encountering some unexpected behaviour in the associativity property of matrix multiplication in both numpy and tensorflow. This is causing my model (written in tensorflow) to give some unexpected errors when computing the Cholesky decomposition of covariance matrices.

Below is a simple working example of this (the model actually uses 3D and 4D tensors):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Generate random matrices sampled from normal distribution
M = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, size=(5, 5))
C = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, size=(5, 5))
```

First we check numpy output:

```
r1 = np.matmul(np.matmul(M, C),np.transpose(M))
r2 = np.matmul(M, np.matmul(C, np.transpose(M)))
r3 = (M @ C) @ np.transpose(M)
r4 = M @ (C @ np.transpose(M))
print("r1 == r2: ", np.all(r1 == r2))
print("r1 == r3: ", np.all(r1 == r3))
print("r1 == r4: ", np.all(r1 == r4))
print("r2 == r3: ", np.all(r2 == r3))
print("r2 == r4: ", np.all(r2 == r4))
print("r3 == r4: ", np.all(r3 == r4))
```

We get the following result:
[Numpy's result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL6YI.png)

The we check tensorflow output:

```
# Check tensorflow
t1 = tf.linalg.matmul(tf.linalg.matmul(M, C), M, transpose_b = True)
t2 = tf.linalg.matmul(M, tf.linalg.matmul(C, M, transpose_b = True))
print("t1 == t2: ", np.all(t1.numpy() == t2.numpy()))
print(t1.numpy() - t2.numpy())
```

We get the following result:
[Tensorflow's results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aboQt.png)

I found a similar thread describing a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41046737/associativity-of-matrix-multiplication-in-numpy), but with no answer.

Do you think that differences in the order of approximately *e-19* can have such an impact that causes these weight matrices to not have a Cholesky decomposition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the true pairs for numpy are doing the same calc.  `@` is the `matmul` operator.  As for the decomp, how close is your array to being singular?

Comment: @hpaulj In the implementation of the model we have a covariance matrix C (which was obtained via Choleasky decomposition) and then we apply the linear transformation M as M*C*M^T which should itself be a covariance matrix. To test this we set M as the identity matrix and to our surprise C was different than I*C*I^T. This then caused some floating point changes which then made the Cholesky decomp of I*C*I^T impossible. We were trying to understand how accurate the matrix multiplications are. Hope this was clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "impossible"?  For that matter, I should have complained about the original "unexpected errors".  For example, when I try `np.linalg.cholesky(C)` for a random C from your code, I get an `LinAlgError: Matrix is not positive definite`.